# Rails mailer smtp authentication error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, mailer

my mailer can't work because of this error. I can't understannd why. I use G-suite for my email.

[image]

Thanks very much for your help !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Reason**: Google was blocking access from unknown location (app in production)

**Solution**: go to following link and turn on https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, recently Google really blocked  the access to less secure apps.

But, you could resolve it turning on the 2 steps verification log in, and then the option app password should be allowed. this feature was created to applications that cant' make the 2 steps verification. Google will register a diferent password to be only accessed from this app.

https://www.google.com/settings/security
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=pt-BR